# Simulating traffic on Flask app with Curl Command

Tags: flask, curl

I have a flask app that I'm trying to do a simple curl command against it to simulate traffic. However, whenever I try to do the curl command against the IP/port:

curl 0.0.0.0:5050

My pointer just moves down the screen and nothing happens. I eventually have to CTRL + C to close out of it. Any thoughts on how to keep the app open and try and ping it to simulate traffic?

[image: flask app running followed by curl command]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the same terminal window for both the running of the Flask-server and the `curl` command. That won't work, because the terminal is busy working the Flask-server. Simple solution would be to open a new terminal window and commission your `curl` command in that one.